# correct way of Setting pythonpath

Tags: python, environment-variables, pythonpath

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/usr/bin/python')    
vs
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = '/usr/bin/python'
```

I am running a script as a cron job and want to set PYTHONPATH environ variable to '/usr/bin/python' for the script to be run. What is the correct way of of the two mentioned in the snippet above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating `sys.path.append()` will change the paths that the current script searches for modules/packages. Updating `os.environ[]` will only affect subprocesses, if you pass them the environment.
These only affect the directories that are searched for modules/packages, as `/usr/bin/python` is usually the python executable neither would have any effect.

If you are trying to specify a version of python to use to execute the script then use a shebang at the top of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Make sure the script is set executable `chmod +x script` and then execute it directly via cron.

Comment: Both the statments work. I want to know the difference between sys.path.append('/usr/bin/python')   and os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = '/usr/bin/python'

Comment: This is exactly wat i wanted. I am running sub scripts from the main script as subprocesses. So for each of the subscript I run , I need to change the environment var's. SO I guess from ur explaination , I should user os.environ[]. Thanks a lot!